# Why is the PJSIP's jitter buffer prefetching disabled by default?

Tags: voip, audio-streaming, pjsip, jitter

PJSIP has a feature for jitter buffer named prefetching. Defined [here](https://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMED__JBUF.htm#gac6a412071169a75601afdcd2fb9ed820): "Setting this to other than 0 will activate prefetch buffering, a jitter buffer feature that each time it gets empty, it won't return a normal frame until its size reaches the number specified here." It is exported here at [PJSUA](https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/blob/master/pjsip/include/pjsua-lib/pjsua.h#L6840) level: "If the value is 0, prefetching will be disabled." And it is disabled by default, meaning that all the adaptive jitter buffer algorithm work is useless by default. The downside I see is a little bit of latency (150ms, by example), while by not using it the jitter buffer loses the ability to adapt to poor networks.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't disabled in default configuration, see pjsua_media_config_default() function.

Comment: It is: `cfg->jb_init = cfg->jb_min_pre = cfg->jb_max_pre = cfg->jb_max = -1;`  and then in pjmedia_stream_create():    `jb_init = 0;` if less than frame's ptime.